# In C++ template arguments, is it possible to specify the type and number of occurrence of that type?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a variadic template class in C++ (similar to `std::tuple`). When instantiating the class, I need to type a lot of types, e.g.

```
MyClass<int, int, double, double, double> my_obj;
```

This approach works when the number of types is small. However, say if I have 10 `ints` followed by 20 `doubles`, typing it would be cumbersome and error-prone.

Is there is mechanism in C++, to specify types followed by number of occurrence in the `template <>` argument? Something like this:

```
MyClass<some_magic(int,2), some_magic(double, 3)> my_obj;
```

Comment: Tuples and variadic template arguments perhaps?

Comment: Short answer: no there isn't. One could, perhaps, write some helper templates that will work out the actual underlying variadic parameter pack starting with some shorter, more compact, designation. But that's going to be more trouble than its worth. Sounds like whatever the reason this is done, there's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Boost.PP could do it. Or redesign the class template to accept meta-arguments...

Comment: @user10605163 I created a static dataframe class with multiple columns of potentially different types.

Comment: How is the object constructed? You may be able to solve it via template argument deduction, so you don't need to specify types manually. (My previous comment was not helpful because I misread the question.)

Comment: For the sake of this question we can assume my class is like a std::tuple but with a lot of repeated types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will make it:

```
namespace detail{
    template <class T, auto> using always_t = T;

    template <class T, std::size_t... Idx>
    auto repeat_impl(std::index_sequence<Idx...>) -> std::tuple<always_t<T, Idx>...>;

    template <class T, class...>
    struct pack
    {
        using type = T;
    };
    template <class... T, class... R, class... Tuple>
    struct pack<std::tuple<T...>, std::tuple<R...>, Tuple...>
        : pack<std::tuple<T..., R...>, Tuple...>
    { };

    template <class> struct tuple_to_class;
    template <class... T> struct tuple_to_class<std::tuple<T...>>
    {
        using type = MyClass<T...>;
    };
}

template <class T, std::size_t N>
using repeat_t = decltype(detail::repeat_impl<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));

template <class... Repeats>
using ToMyClass = typename detail::tuple_to_class<typename detail::pack<Repeats...>::type>::type;
```

---

```
using C = MyClass<int, int, double, double, double>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<C,
              ToMyClass<repeat_t<int, 2>, repeat_t<double, 3>>
              >);
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc0cbd0cc871dbd9)</kbd>